# Powershell: pass system key as a argument

Tags: powershell

I want to pass -Unique as parameter for select-string

```
param(
    $y="CAR"
    $parameter=""
)
get-childitem -r -i "*.txt"| select-string "TABLE FILE $y" | Select-Object filename,path $parameter
```

But whenever i try to pass the parameter, i get the following error

```
powershell : Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-Unique'.
At line:1 char:1
+ powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File x.ps1 -parameter '-Unique'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Select-Object :...ment '-Unique'.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

At C:\Users\aravikumar\Downloads\x.ps1:5 char:62
+ ... elect-string "TABLE FILE $y" | Select-Object filename,path $parameter
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

Also want to pass multiple system key if possible such as -unique -simplesearch -casesensitive

Comment: where are you passing this `powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File x.ps1 -parameter '-Unique'` . Post the script fully

Comment: That is the full script . I am passing -unique in  a select-object cmdlet. You can see that in the first code snippet.

Comment: You said you want to pass `-Unique` as a parameter to `Select-String`, but it appears you are passing it to the `Select-Object` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a switch as a string parameter like that.   You need to use a technique called 'splatting'.   See `help about_splatting` or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting

Comment: Thanks! This is what i was looking for.